# pgAdmin4 can't connect to local pgsql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, manjaro

OS: Manjaro Gnome
Error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

connection failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Address not available
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

i am running pgadmin4 image on docker,installed pgsql with pacman
firewall status are:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

[pgadmin4 on Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4J5Q.png)

Configration:
[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMf1b.png)

```
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
#custom
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU7EV.png)

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

[.zshrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oauK.png)
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

solution:
well it worded after i
set pgadmin4 config 'host' to **'192.168.0.105'** which is my ‘ host IP address‘.

for i didn't start docker learning ,notice that,we can't connect to localhost directly but access 'host ip address'.

sure that worked. thanks to chatgpt.
Docker and linux learning is really important!